# How can i create SQL Agent job in SQL Server 2008 standard?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-agent

How can I create job in SQL Server 2008 Standard Edition?

I cannot find the menu for the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command in SQL Server Management Studio to create a new SQL Agent job is under the SQL Sever Agent node. Right click on the Jobs directory, and select New Job.

[image: New SQL AGent job]