# Create a task in SQL or Windows Server to clean a directory nightly

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, delete-file

I have a temp directory on my website where users export data in .csv files.

The newer intranet apps delete the file after it's sent to the client but the legacy apps just leave the files in this directory.

I'd like to create a task to clean this directory nightly.  There can be .csv files and directories with files in them.

Basically I want to run:

```
del *.* /s
rd /s
```

...every night at midnight.

Would love to do it with a SQL maintenance task but that only runs on the actual SQL server and doesn't work with mapped drives (unless I'm missing something).

How does one go about performing this task?

Can it be done through SQL server somehow?

Comment: Why bother? Just make a script and run it as a scheduled task in Windows.

Comment: How do I do that?  Using the task scheduler?

Comment: Yeah, just save what you have as a `.bat` file, and use the task scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You have the option of creating "Jobs" that run stored procedures or bits of code. These jobs can be scheduled to run daily, weekly, etc. Check out this thread: [How can i create SQL Agent job in SQL Server 2008 standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321391/how-can-i-create-sql-agent-job-in-sql-server-2008-standard)

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do that, I was just wondering if you can create a job to delete files located on another server.  When I create a maintenance task for cleanup, I can only access local drives, not any network resources, even if the drive is mapped.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can apply a job to a non local server by using Transact-SQL. This site may be of some help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178622.aspx

Comment: Sorry, that was for 2012. This is 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187763(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be using SQL Server Express Edition for which Microsoft removed the SQL Agent on 2008 and above. In cases like this you're best choice is using the Windows Scheduler to run your commands via a batch file.